# ASP.Net C# - Datalist Not Complex Enough - Adding Item Data From Secondary Tables

Tags: c#, datalist

I have a datalist that is generated from a database table with the query that is something like this.

```
SELECT Product_Type, Unit_Type, Image FROM Products WHERE ProductID = 1 Or ProductID = 2 OR ProductID = 3... etc.
```

I want to display a pie graph for each item in the datalist that would rely on data from another table for the chart.  The data in this secondary table can be selected with ProductID as well.

My issue is that the datalist seems to be run from a single SELECT to a table.  Is there a way for me to instruct the datalist to retrieve supplemental data from a secondary table for EACH item in the datalist?

Comment: You need to use a JOIN to combine more than one table.

Comment: @jdweng, the problem is how do I create a pie chart for ProductID = 1 (for example) for the datalist item when my main SELECT is asking "WHERE ProductID = 1 Or ProductID = 2 Or ProductID = 3..."?  It's like I need a sub select for each item.

Comment: You need a JOIN and then a GROUP to get a count of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read up on how to join tables, here is an article to get you started: [Join Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Below is a simple example of a join to get more information on a product. We really don't know much about the table with the other data, but hopefully this will get you started. In this example you can see how to get the sales amount based on the foreign key in the prodcut sales table:

```
CREATE TABLE #product
(
    productId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL    
)

CREATE TABLE #productSales
(
    salesId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    productId INT NOT NULL,
    amount INT NOT NULL    
)

INSERT INTO #product VALUES(1, 'Boat')
INSERT INTO #product VALUES(2, 'Raft')
INSERT INTO #product VALUES(3, 'Canoe')

INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(1, 1, 10)
INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(2, 1, 89)
INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(3, 2, 410)
INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(4, 2, 10997)
INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(5, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(6, 2, 98)
INSERT INTO #productSales VALUES(7, 3, 14)

SELECT p.productId, p.description, ps.amount from #product p 
    INNER JOIN #productSales ps on 
     p.productId = ps.productId
WHERE p.productId IN (1,2,3)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1   Boat    10
1   Boat    89
2   Raft    410
2   Raft    10997
2   Raft    3
2   Raft    98
3   Canoe   14
```